# Securely passing hidden id for nested forms on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, security, nested-attributes

I have User and Profile models. User `has_one` Profile which `belongs_to` User. Profile also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` and I am building a form for Profile, which takes some attributes for user too.

In order to have my `profile.user` updated (not created), I must provide an `id` under the nested attributes for user form, which I do it through a hidden input.

The problem is that I don't think this is safe because one might change the id on the client side and the server would update another user instance, other than the profile's one.

To avoid this, on Profile's controller, I manually append the id for `user_attributes` on params which corresponds to the `current_user.id`, but I think that's not the best way to do it.

Is there any other way to ensure that Rails will be updating the actual profile's user or, in case the client supplies an user id different of its `profile.user`, it would prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `URI` such as `/user/123/profile` you can obtain the user's id from the `URI` `params` and compare it to `current_user.id` if they match, great, if not, error.